# Need help implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, mvvm, interface

in my application I am wanting to make my interfaces more generic. As it stands I have  Two Models, CampaignModel and StringModel, these both use the same methods but with different arguments in them i.e.

CampaignModel:

```
void GetAll(EventHandler<GetAllCampaignsCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void GetAllByName(string name, EventHandler<GetCampaignCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void GetAllByID(long id, EventHandler<GetAllCampaignsByIDCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void Add(Campaign entity, EventHandler<CreateCampaignCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void Update(Campaign entity, EventHandler<UpdateCampaignCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void Delete(Campaign entity, EventHandler<DeleteCampaignCompletedEventArgs> eh);
```

StringsModel:

```
void GetAll(EventHandler<GetAllCampaignStringsCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void GetAllByName(string name, EventHandler<GetCampaignStringByIdentifierCompletedEventArgs> eh);
void GetAllByID(long id, EventHandler<EventArgs> eh);
void Add(CampString entity, EventHandler<EventArgs> eh);
void Update(CampString entity, EventHandler<EventArgs> eh);
void Delete(CampString entity, EventHandler<EventArgs> eh);
```

I am just needing direction as to how to create a more generic interface that I can use. The reason for this is I only want one set of Views for each Models .i.e only one Add,Update and Delete view that will call the methods from either the Campaign Model or the Strings Model. If you have any ideas how to get this done I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Stuart.

Comment: so you would basically like to have one interface for those 2 (perhaps in the future more) models?

Comment: Yes, but with different parameters in the method signatures.

Comment: If by different parameters you mean different Types then `Tigran` 's answer pretty much covers the problem by using inheritance. Note that in his solution `BaseCampaign : IBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code you can see that, at least in the functions you provided, what  changes between two clases is a *type* of paremeters. The common approach here is to define a Base type for every common group, so here is *pseudocode*:

```
public class GetCampaignCompletedEventArgs : BaseEventArg {} 
public class GetCampaignStringByIdentifierCompletedEventArgs: BaseEventArg {} 
... 
...
public class Campaign : BaseCampaign {} 
public class CampString: BaseCampaign {}
```

After this defin *Interface* or *AbstractClass*

```
public interface IBase {
void GetAllByName(string name, EventHandler<BaseEventArg > eh);
...
```

}

Just to give yuor idea, its difficult to me write somethign really concrete , cause its depends on yuor implementaiton.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This issue with this is that the EventArgs that are in the methods are taken from a WCF Web Service so I don't have much control over those as they are generated in the proxy.

Comment: @sturtmclark: in this case you can not change them, but you can change "yourself" :) I mean INCAPSULATE those classes into your Facade class , so YOUR methods will deal with YOUR Facade class, which under the hood works with WCF proxy type.